Struggling with Loops in Python
I am a beginner with Python and trying to learn loops, but I am struggling a lot. Specifically with the below problem.
mystery_int = 50

#You may modify the lines of code above, but don't move them!
#When you Submit your code, we'll change these lines to
#assign different values to the variables.

#Write a for loop that prints every third number from 1 to
#mystery_int inclusive (meaning that if mystery_int is 7, it
#prints 1, 4, and 7). Print each number on a separate line.
#
#Hint: There are multiple ways to do this! You might use the
#modulus operators, or you could use the third argument for
#range().

#Add your code here!

for i in range (1, mystery_int + 1):
    i = i + 3
    print (i)

I was expecting this to print 1, 4, 7, 9 etc
But it printed 4, 5, 6, 7 etc.

The main point is that you need to recognize how stepping works in for loops (check @MinhDang's answer). @Himars gives a good example of how to use that. Also, quick note, in order to add 3 to a variable, you can use this expression instead: i += 3.

i = i + 3 This adds 3 to i before it is printed.  Why would you expect it to print 1 on the first iteration?

Even though you are adding 3 to i inside the loop, i is also the loop variable, so it is assigned the next range value each time through the loop, forgetting its previous value.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range
In [1]: mystery = 4

In [2]: list(range(1, mystery))
Out[2]: [1, 2, 3]

In [3]: for i in range(1, 4):
   ...:     print(i)
   ...:     print("i+3=", i+3)
   ...:
1
i+3= 4
2
i+3= 5
3
i+3= 6

In [5]: list(range(1, 50, 3))
Out[5]: [1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16, 19, 22, 25, 28, 31, 34, 37, 40, 43, 46, 49]

What the question is trying to show is that you can change the step size of range. By default, step is 1

You can do it something like this:
mystery_int = 50
for i in range(1, mystery_int + 1, 3):
    print(i)

Or you can do it like this:
mystery_int = 50
i = 1
while i <= mystery_int:
    print(i)
    i += 3

Or like this:
mystery_int = 50
ranges = [x * 3 + 1 for x in range((mystery_int + 2) // 3)]
print(ranges)

In fact, there are a lot of options.

There are two ways to do this, modulus and the third operator of range.
The first way goes through all the values and only outputs when a value is valid. A value in this if valid if it modulus three is equal to 1. That's because modulus is just remainder. Like so:
mystery_int = 7
for i in range(1, mystery_int + 1):
    if i % 3 == 1:
        print(i)

Or you can do it with the third operator of range which is how much it jumps by each time so i jumps by 3 if the third opertor of range is 3. Starting from zero it would go: 0, 3, 6, 9, etc... The code would be:
mystery_int = 7
for i in range(1, mystery_int + 1, 3):
    print(i)

the problem with your code is it outputs every value less than seven plus 3 so  i+3 (i being the amount below seven)

If you are printing after updating, you should print first then update:
for i in range (1, mystery_int + 1):
   print (i)
   i = i + 3

You can also write:
for i in range(1, mystery_int + 1, 3):
    print(i)

now i will increase by 3 every time.

The question suggests that you might want to take advantage of the third argument to range which is the step count.
With that in mind you could do this (without an explicit loop):
mystery_int = 50

print(*range(1, mystery_int+1, 3), sep="\n")

In this case, the range generates numbers from 1 to the stop value (minus 1) in steps of 3.
The other suggestion in the question is to use the modulo operator which you could do like this:
for i in range(1, mystery_int+1):
    if i % 3 == 1:
        print(i)

Here i is incremented by 1 (the default step value) so you have to check each value in turn

check here:
print (i)
i = i + 3

